# Use multiple values from an array of matched rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
Name   |   Start   |   Amount   | Growth Rate | Initial
Test1  |     1     |     100    |     0.5     |   0.1
Test2  |     2     |     100    |     0.2     |   0.2
```

Basically I want the aggregate sum of `Amount * Initial * (1 + Growth Rate)^a` for all rows where `start < b`, where `a` and `b` are variables supplied by other cells. I managed to make this work with a disgusting `IF` statement (array formula), but I was unable to use a `MIN` to cap the percentage at 100%. In other words, `Initial * (1 + Growth Rate)^a` should never exceed 1 (I can never get more than 100% of the Amount).

Comment: Formula or vba?

Comment: @Raystafarian Preferably formula if it's possible

Comment: Would you add your current formula to the question? and an example of a and b? Or upload a scrubbed copy of your worksheet?